# Dropdownlist selected value at Selectedindexchanged event

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedindexchanged

I'm working on asp.net website with Vb.net and I have a dropdownlist with autopostback = true and I need to get the selected value when I change the item or I want to get the item which fires the selectedindexchanged event ..

any help please..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ie. your Page_Load set

```
this.ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Then write the event handler like this:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
  string selected = (string) comboBox.SelectedItem;
}
```

Make sure that in your Page_Load you write this before setting the combobox default value or you will end up with this always being the selected item:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
  return;
```

Comment: I edited my answer, you need to be aware that the Page_Load is executed before the SelectedIndexChanged, so anything you do with the combobox here will affect your result. Use the if statement in the top section of Page_Load.

Comment: shouldn't this: `ComboBox1.SelectedItem;` be this: `comboBox.SelectedItem;` ?

Comment: It's amazing how the OP specified in the question that he's working on a asp.net website with **Vb.net** but all the answers on here are C#?? lol

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
    protected void list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
        string value = (string)list.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: This gives me a SelectedValue of whatever the Initial setting is rather than the newly selected setting.

Answer (score 0):

If item is a Dictionary:

```
string value = ((KeyValuePair<string, string>)combobox.SelectedItem).Key;
```