# How to get selected value of item from dropdownlist inside formview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to get the value of the selected item in a dropdown list that's inside the edit template of a formview control.  The formview ID is "fvDocRvwrs".

Here's the markup for the dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList SelectedValue='<%# Bind("rvwStat") %>' runat="server" ID="rvwStatDdl" CssClass="form-control" DataSourceID="sdsStatuses" DataTextField="stat" DataValueField="statIdPk" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rvwStatDdl_SelectedIndexChanged"><asp:ListItem Value="">--Please Select--</asp:ListItem></asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm just having some difficulty getting the SelectedValue using the onselectedindexchanged event of the dropdownlist.  I am able to find the control using:

```
protected void rvwStatDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var statVal = fvDocRvwrs.FindControl("rwStatDdl").ToString();
    }
```

I just need to know how to populate a variable with the selected value.

Comment: You are not able to do `var statval = rvwStatDdl.SelectedValue;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should cast as **DropDownList** after finding control

```
var statVal = ((DropDownList)fvDocRvwrs.FindControl("rwStatDdl")).SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the SelectedValue property.

Try 
`protected void name_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)sender;
        string value = list.SelectedValue;}`

Credit: [Dropdownlist selected value at Selectedindexchanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371187/dropdownlist-selected-value-at-selectedindexchanged-event) Frank Lee's answer